# How does one redirect using HTML and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have a captcha integration within my login page, and I want to redirect my page on clicking login after it has captcha validation. however the redirecting isn't working

```html
<button type="submit" id="log" name="log" onclick="redirect()" > Log in here</button><br><br>

<Center>

<b>Captcha Verification : </b><br>

<div class="capt"> 


<center><h3 type="text" id="mainCaptcha"></h3></center>
<script>
function redirect(){
    if (ValidateCaptcha()) {
          Location.replace("redirect.html");
        } else {
          alert("Please complete the captcha to log in."); 
        }
    
}
</script>
```

`ValidateCaptcha` is handled elsewhere and is irrelevant (it does work thought). When I give the `redirect()` function any other action to carry out like `alert("yay");`, it works, but location method redirecting. What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to redirect to a new page on pressing the log in button.

Comment: Your HTML seems malformed as well. Your `Center` and `div` tags are unclosed.

Comment: Just an aside: center tag is deprecated - use CSS instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Typo: JavaScript is case sensitive. `location` doesn’t start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `Location` correctly. Assuming you want to use vanilla JS:

- If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use
  `location.href`
- If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`

Examples:

```js
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); // or "/redirect.html"

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; // or "/redirect.html"
```

---

###### Update

Try to set some debug logs within your code (most basic debugging):

```
<script>
function redirect(){
    console.log('Function called');
    if (ValidateCaptcha()) {
          console.log('We are within ValidateCaptcha check');
          window.location.href = "redirect.html";
        } else {
          console.log('ValidateCaptcha check failed');
          alert("Please complete the captcha to log in."); 
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i tried using both of these, its still not working

Comment: What is the error? "still not working" does not help anyone here to figure out what exact errors you experience.. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: when i click the log in button after entering the right captcha, it doesnt redirect to another page

Comment: What does it do? What does the browser console show? Have you tried setting `console.log('debug, I am at step 1,2,3');` before and after the JS calls you do, to determine where your script fails and what it reaches, if it does? You can try so many things. Have you searched Internet on how to debug JS? What did you try?

Answer (score -1):

close div and center tag first.
**In Script**

> Location.replace("/redirect.html");
> or
> window.location.href = "/redirect.html";